# Unable to fill gap between meshes

Tags: mesh

[image]
Hi, I'm unable to fill gap between wrist and hand. I've tried pressing 'F' but it doesn't work

Comment: try ctrl E > Bridge Edge Loops

Comment: That also doesn't work

Comment: so maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=lRkZv1Da" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/lRkZv1Da/)

Comment: these are 2 different objects, you need first to join them (ctrl J)

Comment: Thanks it worked. But there's dark shading a long where I join and in between the fingers. Why is that?

Comment: the normals of the hand are flipped, in Edit mode, select all and Alt N to recalculate the Normals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are 2 different objects, you need first to join them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>) otherwise you won't be able to bridge the 2 edge loops.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried filling just one quad (i.e. selecting two vertices on the hand and two vertices on the wrist)?

Because they won't join or fill as a group unless they have the same number of vertices.